# Low dimensional classifying map determining $\mathcal{O}(k)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$Consider the line bundles $\mathcal{O}(k)$ on $\P^n$.  I know that there is a map  in $[\P^n,\P^\infty]=[\P^n,\P^n]$ classifying this line bundle.  Here brackets denote homotopy classes of maps

More precisely, there is a map $\P^n\ \xrightarrow{\ f\ }\ \P^n$ such that $f^*$ (the canonical line bundle over $\P^n$) is $\mathcal{O}(k)$.

> Can $f$ be chosen to be holomorphic?

---

Selected ramblings of mine:

The reason why I ask is because the [when there are global sections(i.e. when $k\geq 0$, the standard map to projective space given by the line bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4567/maps-to-projective-space-determined-by-a-line-bundle) is to projective space of dimension $\dim\Bbb{C}[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]_k$ which is much bigger than $n$.

Moreover the only way I know how to construct such a map is by using a partition of unity which is not a holomorphic respecting construction.

Suppose $x \in U_{i_o}=D_{x_{i_0}} \subset \P^n$.  Let $t_{ij}$ be algebraic transition functions for a line bundle (like that for $\mathcal{O}(k)$). **Then $[t_{i_00}:t_{i_01}:\cdots:t_{i_0n}]$ is well defined on the intersections of $\bigcap U_i$ and is a well defined map as soon as one clears denominators.**  This seems like a good candidate for a classifying map since if one is given a partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}$, then the corresponding classifying map should be $[\phi_0t_{i_00}:\phi_1t_{i_01}:\cdots:\phi_nt_{i_0n}]$.

Comment: Is your canonical line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ or $\mathcal{O}(-1)$? Depending on that, you can take ANY finite map (in particular algebraic) of degree $k>0$, $f$ from $\mathbb{P}^n$ to itself and then $f^*(\mathcal{O}(1))=\mathcal{O}(k)$.

Comment: Yes - $[\P^n,\P^n]=Z$ is realized by degree.